# how to hide website assets such as js and css files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I came across the following index.html page in which i didn't find any custom assets, such as js and css files. The assets path is as follows

[image]

I am not able to find where we have included assets/css/custom/.css assets/js/custom/.js files.

Is there a way to hide these css and js file from html code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Where passion meets potential</title>
</head>

    <body>
        <!-- start of loading jquery -->
        <script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/vendor/lazyload/lazyload.js"></script>
        <!-- Loading angular and angular route via CDN -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.2.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Loading Angular Controller -->
        <script src="controller.js"></script>

        <!-- using lazyload to load our dependencies programatically -->
        <script src="assets/js/vendor/lazyload/application-css.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/vendor/lazyload/application-js.js"></script>

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div id="main">
            <!-- angular template injection-->
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
        <!-- END Content -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read about minification of code

Comment: `<!-- using lazyload to load our dependencies programatically -->` - nothing is “hidden” here, those resources are just added dynamically via the scripts following that comment.

Comment: thanks @cBroe I am talking about assets/css/custom/landing.css and  assets/js/custom/landing.js . i am not able to understand how that these js and css file is include in index.html

Comment: The scripts mentioned _dynamically insert_ them into the DOM (by creating `link` and `script` elements and appending them to the document.)

Comment: Thanks @cBroe . :)

Answer (score 2):

Just read the comments. A library called lazyload is used to load all dependencies, probably from the folders you named.

```
<!-- using lazyload to load our dependencies programatically -->
<script src="assets/js/vendor/lazyload/application-css.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/vendor/lazyload/application-js.js"></script>
```

I don't know how it works exactly but I assume it will add the lazily loaded files somewhere to the DOM. The client will always be able to find those resources somehow (e.g. the network tab of chrome devtools).
The files in the code above will probably contain information about how it works for your project.

Comment: Thanks @schrej for answer the css and js mention are in the lazyload  and its been dynamically loaded.